# System.Net.NetworkInformation IPv4Mask not working in MonoTouch?

Tags: ios, networking, xamarin.ios

I use the following code to get a list of network interfaces currently available on the iPhone:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface l__objNetworkInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation l__objIPAddress in l__objNetworkInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
    {
        if (l__objAddress.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            if (l__objAddress.IPv4Mask != null) Console.WriteLine("IPv4 Mask: " + l__objAddress.IPv4Mask.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

My Problem: Calling the property IPv4Mask seems to block the code (the IPv4Mask is never output to the console and the iPhone-Simulator seems to stop processing at the calling point).

Does anyone know this problem? Is the IPv4Mask property not implemented in monotouch (I can't find any clear infos about this on monotouch or google)?

Answer (score 3):

The `IPv4Mask` [is not implemented](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/UnicastIPAddressInformation.cs#L167) for UnicastIPAddresses in mono.

You also seem to have a typo in your code, you loop over `l__objIPAddress` in your second foreach, but then you access `l__objAddress` inside the loop.

Comment: It seems that in the platform call for MacOs the structure ifaddrs contains the subnet mask. It is just not hooked up to IPv4Mask property in the U/nicastIPAddress class.

Comment: @Krumelur: most likely because nobody took the time to do it.