# How do I enumerate ipv4 addresses and ipv4mask using Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to enumerate the ip address and the subnet mask for all network interfaces using iOS.

```
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface[] nics = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        foreach (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface nic in nics)
        {
            var ipProps = nic.GetIPProperties();

            // We're only interested in IPv4 addresses for this example.
            var ipv4Addrs = ipProps.UnicastAddresses
                .Where(addr => addr.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

            foreach (var addr in ipv4Addrs)
            {
                UnicastIPAddressInformation addrInfo = (UnicastIPAddressInformation)addr;
                IPAddress ipAddr = addrInfo.Address; 
                IPAddress mask = addrInfo.IPv4Mask;

                string x = mask.ToString(); // NotImplementedException is thrown here.
            }
        }
```

It seems to be throwing a NotImplementedException, when I am trying to get the IP4 mask. It seems that Mono does not implement this property.

Is there any other way to do this using Xamarin.iOS classes or iOS API calls?

Comment: Jup, you're right: it's not implemented: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.NetworkInformation/UnicastIPAddressInformation.cs#L165 - see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886389/system-net-networkinformation-ipv4mask-not-working-in-monotouch

Comment: @Krumelur I am running on iOS therefore I am getting  LinuxUnicastIPAddressInformation instead of the Win32 one. For that class the IP4vMask is not implemented unfortunately.

Comment: See me amended comment. Yet I have no idea _why_ it is not implemented.

Comment: See this issue for further discussion: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2033

Answer (score 1):

I tried to scratch my own ich, so I looked into the mono base class library and reused the platform calls found there. I created a small iPhone app enumerating the network interfaces and showing the addresses and the masks.

Here is the github repo with the source code - [NetworkTest](https://github.com/gyurisc/NetworkTest)